Are there domains of enquiry where nonfalsifiability is a good thing, and if so is this formalised?
In science, falsifiability of a theory is considered a good thing because as per Popper if a empirical evidence can show that a theory is false, then the theory can be replaced by another which has not yet been falsified, and hence it's more likely to be an approximation of the truth, or at least it will do a better job of predicting what will happen given various initial states.
This makes sense where the purpose of the theory is to make predictions.
It occurs to me that in domains such as ethics, if your theory states e.g. that people should not take a cookie from the jar without being offered, then the fact that empirical evidence that this sometimes in fact happens, not only is not a refutation, it also becomes increasingly irrelevant the higher the stakes of the ethical value in question. So we might say that non-falsifiability, at least of the empirical sort, is baked in. And this is because making predictions is not a core purpose of ethics, it has other purposes instead.
Is there a name for this property, and could it be generalized to other domains?
Given that there is a chance religion could come up in this context, I guess it could be said that non-falsifiability in religion could be a good thing to the extent that a religion is more like an ethical system and less like a science, but this is not what I'm asking.

This distinction originates from Hume’s is-ought gap which posits difference between descriptive synthetic empirical facts and normative ethics. Some would argue that modern sophisticated category theory as one candidate foundation of math expresses ought-like morality which obviously cannot be falsified or falsifiable…

What makes something a good or bad thing is itself unfalsifiable, so this question cannot be answered.

The standard terms are positive vs normative statements. Positive ones posit facts and are subject to testing, while normative ones (as in ethics) offer norms or values and are not, at least not in the direct sense that admits falsification. However, many non-normative philosophical or even scientific statements involve broad/vague generalizations or heuristics that are also not directly falsifiable for legitimate reasons. Their purpose is to surmise and to stimulate further inquiry and they are 'tested' by practice in a more diffused way.

Depending on your preferred approach to the philosophy of logic, you might say that logic itself is an unfalsifiable field of enquiry.

You've misunderstood the term here.  "falsifiability" means that something could conceivably happen that would show your theory to be false.  So:

if your theory states that, e.g. that people should not take a cookie from the jar without being offered

Then what sorts of events could you observe that would falsify this theory (i.e. would show this theory to be false)?

someone takes a cookie from a jar without being offered sometimes in fact happens.

Doesn't seem to show this theory to be false, by your own admission.
In fact, what you're looking for is this:
"Someone took a cookie from a jar without being offered, and it was the right thing to do"
THIS event falsifies the original theory.
Now, Ethics isn't generally considered empirical, so it's a bit odd here to actually demand that something be observed in this instance, but let's continue anyway.  Suppose the following happened:
"Alice has hypoglycemia.  Alice and Bob are out one day and Alice suffers an acute drop in blood sugar.  For some reason, a cookie jar full of standard Oreos is nearby with a "not for you!" sign on it.  Undeterred, Bob takes a cookie from the cookie jar and feeds it to Alice, potentially saving Alice's life.  Before the cookie jar owner returns, Bob buys an entire pack of Oreos and puts the unopened pack next to the jar."
IMHO, one might witness this event and feel that "people should not take a cookie from the jar without being offered" is actually FALSE.  Possibly there is a better theory?  Probably our original theory, which had worked so well in so many other cookie-snatching incidents: "people should not take a cookie from jar without being offered" was MOSTLY right, and just needs some nuance to accommodate our new data.
Proposed new theory:  "People should not take a cookie from a jar without being offered, except in a life-or-death scenario."
One can then repeat this process with the new theory, and so on.  This would be the correct application of Popper's logic of scientific discovery to your cookie jar issue.  It seems to me that this ability to revise one's Ethical theories in the face of information that shows one's ethical theory to be false would be a good feature, and actually illustrates nicely how debate in Ethics generally unfolds.

The falsifiability of a theory simply means that the theory can be empirically tested. Thus physics can be empirically tested.
This notion is not so useful for recent physical speculation - aka string theory and loop quantum gravity - where the domain of energy being speculated at, the Planck scale, is far from an energy scale that we can feasibly test for the forseeable future. Nevertheless the speculation is important. This should be compared to the origins of atomism and field theory in antiquity where again the philosophical speculation was far from anything observable with the then current technology. The empirical testing had to wait about two millenia.
Thus in physics, the notion of falsifiability is nuanced.
There are plenty of domains where falsifiability is not important. An important domaim is religion where it is adherence to tradition and scripture that is important. Another important domain os political philosophy where reasoned argument is made from observation of political processes. However, there are attempts to bring this in line with empirical tests - usimg such tools as focus groups and surveys. This is the domain of political science.

IMO your post mixes up the two philosophical disciplines of epistemology and ethics.

Epistemology is about true and false. It deals with descriptive
statements.

Ethics is about right and wrong. It deals with prescriptive or
more general - normative statements.



Many philosophers agree that normative statements are not discovered
but are negotiated by the members of the same social group. A
striking example is the “Theory of Justice” by John Rawls.
Therefore
asking whether the resulting moral is true or false, and falsifiable
or not falsifiable, would be an error of category. Instead one has
to ask wether the specific moral is right or wrong as a means to
reach the goal of the society.

Linking religion to morality is a traditional relict in many
societies.
At least Kohlberg’s study of the moral development of
children shows how this link forms during the ontogenetic development
and by which alternatives it can be – and often actually is –
superseded, see Kohlberg's stages of moral development.


